# Python's pathlib get parent's relative path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pathlib

Consider the following `Path`:

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(r'C:\users\user1\documents\importantdocuments')
```

How can I extract the exact string `documents\importantdocuments` from that `Path`?

I know this example looks silly, the real context here is translating a local file to a remote download link.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the [`PurePath.relative_to()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) to produce a relative path.

You weren't very clear as to how the base path is determined; here are two options:

```
secondparent = path.parent.parent
homedir = pathlib.Path(r'C:\users\user1')
```

then just use `str()` on the `path.relative_to(secondparent)` or `path.relative_to(homedir)` result.

Demo:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> path = pathlib.Path(r'C:\users\user1\documents\importantdocuments')
>>> secondparent = path.parent.parent
>>> homedir = pathlib.Path(r'C:\users\user1')
>>> str(path.relative_to(secondparent))
'documents\\importantdocuments'
>>> str(path.relative_to(homedir))
'documents\\importantdocuments'
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the "starting dot" , e.g. "./my-relative-dir" with `relative_to()`

Answer (score -2):

This works on any OS and every version of Python:

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(p)),os.path.basename(p))
```

This works on python 3:

```
str(p.relative_to(p.parent.parent))
```

Comment: He's using pathlib, he didn't asked for an alternative.